# How to iterate through a UTF-8 string correctly in OCaml?

Tags: utf-8, ocaml

Say I have some input word like "føøbær" and I want a hash table of letter frequencies s.t. f→1, ø→2 – how do I do this in OCaml?

The http://pleac.sourceforge.net/pleac_ocaml/strings.html examples only work on ASCII and https://ocaml-batteries-team.github.io/batteries-included/hdoc2/BatUTF8.html doesn't say how to actually create a BatUTF8.t from a string.

Answer (score 2):

The `BatUTF8` module you refer to defines its type `t` as `string`, thus there is no conversion needed: a `BatUTF8.t` **is** a `string`. Apparently, the module encourages you to `validate` your `string` before using other functions. I guess that a proper way of operating would be something like:

```
let s = "føøbær"
let () = BatUTF8.validate s
let () = BatUTF8.iter add_to_table s
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code of Batteries, I found this `of_string_unsafe`, so perhaps this is the way:

```
open Batteries
BatUTF8.iter (fun c -> …Hashtbl.add table c …) (BatUTF8.of_string_unsafe "føøbær")`
```

although, since it's termed "unsafe" (the doc's don't say why), maybe this is equivalent:

`BatUTF8.iter (fun c -> …Hashtbl.add table c …) "føøbær"`

At least it works for the example word here.

Camomile also seems to iterate through it correctly:

```
module C = CamomileLibraryDefault.Camomile
C.iter (fun c -> …Hashtbl.add table c …) "føøbær"
```

I don't know of the tradeoffs between Camomile and BatUTF8 here, though they end up storing different types (BatUChar vs C.Pervasives.UChar).

Comment: Just for completeness: `BatUTF8.iter` gives you a `BatUChar` to work with; if you want to e.g. output them you can get them back to "plain" byte-strings (each of a single codepoint) with `BatUTF8.of_char c` (confusingly, `UChar.char_of` will turn it into a Latin-1 char – that `of_char` should probably be called of_uchar …).